# Subprocess in python does not return any output, but does when running python in CMD

Tags: python, gcc, subprocess

I am running a command as below:

```
C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe -nostdinc -IC:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Tools\\testfolder\\source\\h\\tmp -E -DTEST_DEFINE=1 C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Tools\\testfolder\\cfile.c
```

When running it via CMD directly, everything works as expected, I get some output directly to CMD.
When running this command via python from CMD, it also works as expected.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output.stdout
```

But when I use these exact 3 lines in a file that I try to run (with print on 3rd line, ofc), eq. in VS code debug mode, the command runs, but there is not output.

There is nothing, no output, no error, just return code 1.

Since I can use the exact same command in python CMD interface, I am struggling to find out why it does not work in my python file.

I will be glad if anyone has a suggestion.

Just for context, I need some way of parsing and processing C preprocessor logic, therefore I opted to use GCC to save some struggles implementing my own parser.
Sadly, more issues came up.

Comment: If your command is a single string instead of a list of arguments, you generally (this is a little less true on Windows, but completely true everywhere else) need `shell=True`. Or, better, need to transform `command` to be a valid argument vector (aka a list).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `capture_output`, you probably need `text=True` if you want text string as opposed to bytes (default).

```py
output = subprocess.run(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)
```

By default, `capture_output=False`, which does not capture the output into the `.stdout` attribute.

Correction: I forgot to remove `stdout=` and `stderr=` when replacing them with `capture_output=`. The correct invocation is:

```py
output = subprocess.run(
    command,
    capture_output=True,
    text=True,
)
```

Comment: You cannot use capture_output together with stdout and stderr. 

Also the behavior is the same, when using one or the other.